# How to modify a HTML-file in Java and save the changes

Tags: java, html, parsing, save

I have to make a simple change to a HTML-Element (add and remove some attributes). The problem is that I have to go through a lot of HTML-files to do that.

How could I automate that? Sure, there are libraries for parsing and modifying HTML, but after looking at a few of them I am getting the feeling that most don't support saving the changes to the HTML-files.

Comment: Which attributes are you planning on removing?  I know my question is a bit irrelevant but...

Comment: Just removing a few obsolete CSS classes.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). There are plenty of examples out there.

Comment: Ah java! see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping